# CreateProcess() not work properly

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

Im using this code to start my program

```
     int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO cif;
    ZeroMemory(&cif,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    if (CreateProcess(L"C:\\test\\test.exe",NULL,
        NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,NULL,NULL,&cif,&pi)==TRUE)
    {
        cout << "process" << endl;
        cout << "handle " << pi.hProcess << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The program starts normal, but immediately fails(not responding and fails). CreateProcess returns true. When I start test.exe not from code it works properly.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you about what's going wrong? You *are* using a debugger, aren't you?

Comment: Which program is crashing, this code that is launching the new process, or `test.exe`?

Comment: What happens if you pass `0` for process creation flag (instead of `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`)? You're passing `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT` as this flag and `NULL` for environment block but are you sure that environment block of the calling process use `UNICODE` characters?

Comment: I found problem that I didnt set environment for test.exe( 8th argument in CreateProcess).
Thanks to all

Comment: @bossman Great, add that as an answer to let everyone know how you solved it.

Answer (score 5):

You have to zero the memory of both STARTUPINFO and PROCESS_INFORMATION, and you have to set the cb field of the STARTUPINFO structure.

Copying the [sample code in the Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx) is a good place to start.

Comment: True, but the OP already left a comment a few minutes ago stating that he found the problem.

Comment: Not setting the cb field is probably not a good idea. It might work on his particular version of Windows. Don't expect it to work on an earlier or later version. Or after a service pack for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem that I didnt set directory for test.exe( 8th argument in CreateProcess). Thanks to all